# C# WinForms (.NET 3.5): ComboBox returns null reference after first selection

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, .net-3.5

**Note:** This is a vanilla WinForms application. No WPF or WCF or anything else.

Hey people, I'm developing a **WinForms (.NET 3.5)** application and am stuck at a problem. I'm trying to get cities based on the selected state (both in 2 different `ComboBox`-es with `DropDownStyle` set to `DropDownList`).

I have implemented this logic in the `SelectedIndexChanged` event handler using the `SelectedValue` property. The `DataSource` is a `DataTable` returned from a DB method, and `SelectedValue` returns an instance of `DataRowView`.

**In the form constructor**, I populate the state ComboBox and programmatically set the default state selection using `SelectedIndex` property; this then goes to the event handler, **executes properly, and populates the city** **`ComboBox`** for that state.

Now the problem comes when I change the selected state **post-construction**, when the form is up & running, using my mouse. This again goes to the event handler, but the `SelectedValue` property **returns a null reference**. Please help. I'm attaching the code below.

```
private void comboFindState_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            DataRowView selectedState;
            int selectedStateId;
            DataTable citiesTable;

            selectedState = comboFindState.SelectedValue as DataRowView;


            if (selectedState != null) //Is true the first time around when the event is
            //triggered due to programmatic change of the index.
            //Then null afterwards, on change via mouse click.
            {
                selectedStateId = Convert.ToInt32(selectedState.Row["State Code"]);
                citiesTable = DatabaseHelper.getStateCities(selectedStateId);

                comboFindCity.DataSource = citiesTable; //Same binding for state ComboBox
                //in the form's constructor;
                comboFindCity.DisplayMember = "City"; //only here it says "State",
                comboFindCity.ValueMember = "City Code";// and here it says "State Code".

                comboFindCity.SelectedIndex = 0; //Same thing in the form's constructor for
                //setting default selected index of state ComboBox.
            }
            else
            {
                //just populates an error TextBox saying 'No Cities Found'
            }
        }
```

Note that all this is happening for the state `ComboBox`, which is already populated. The city `ComboBox` doesn't even enter the scope the second time, so there's no database problem.

**EDIT:** FYI, I have set the `ValueMember` property for t`comboFindState` from the **absolute start**. So that was not the reason why it didn't work. Also note that it worked properly the first time around, hence proving that the `ValueMember` is set properly.

Comment: Can you try replacing the comboFindState.SelectedValue with comboFindState.SelectedItem?

Comment: And voila! It works! You sir/ma'am, shall be termed my savior. However, I still don't understand why `SelectedValue` didn't work the second time around. Any thoughts on this matter?

Comment: As Fabio explained, the problem is in the use of DataSource property. You need to have set the ValueMember.

Comment: I have set the `ValueMember` property. Only difference from Fabio's code is I first set the `DataSource`, and then the `ValueMember`. Which seems the logical thing to do, else how will the compiler know what 'State Code'  means if the `DataSource` is null? If it's different, do explain.

Comment: You can set `ValueMember` in both ways, before or after `DataSource`. It is possible if you set `ValueMember` after assigning `DataSource`, then some extra checking of new `ValueMember` with datasource properties/columns will be executed.

Comment: @Fabio, okay, that was a deep insight. Thank you for clearing that. Now the original question still remains. Why did `SelectedValue` work the first time around (when event was triggered programatically) and not the second time (when event was triggered through mouse click)?

Comment: Can you show code where `ComboBox` was populating with `DataSource`?

Comment: As in from the constructor? Both `ComboBox`es are populated the same way as written in the above event handler code. Only the objects change. Rest is all the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `DataSource` properly, without workarounds.
Before setting `DataSource` set property `ValueMember` to the column name which you using for getting cities

```
comboFindState.ValueMember = "State Code";
comboFindState.DisplayMember = "StateName"; //will be displayed in the combobox
comboFindState.DataSource = yourDataTableOfStates;
```

Then `SelectedValue` will return value of `State Code` as integer type (boxed in the Object type)
or `null` if `comboFindState.SelectedIndex = -1`

```
private void comboFindState_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comboFindState.SelectedValue != null)
    {
        int selectedStateId = (int)comboFindState.SelectedValue;
        DataTable citiesTable = DatabaseHelper.getStateCities(selectedStateId);

        //Your code after getting list of the cities
    }
}
```

In the addition
If you will set `ValueMember` then you can use `SelectedValueChanged` event

...About comments...
*how will the compiler know what 'State Code' means if the DataSource is null? If it's different, do explain*
Compiler have nothing to do with this question. This happens in the runtime
When you set `ValueMember` while `DataSource` is `null`(**before**). Then value of `ValueMember` will be saved and used only when you calling `SelectedValue`.
If `ValueMember` cannot be find from properties/columns of `DataSource`, then whole selected object will be returned, in case when `DataSource` is `DataTable` `DataRowView` will be returned

When you set `ValueMember` while `DataSource` is not `null`(**after**).
Then new value of `ValueMember` will be checked if properties/columns exists in the Type of `DataSource`. If not existed, then `ArgumentException` will be thrown

Comment: _Then SelectedValue will return value of State Code as integer type (boxed in the Object type)_ - This is not happening. It returns a DataRowView object. If I try directly converting or casting the SelectedValue object to int or string, it throws me an InvalidCastException.This is what annoys me the most. Instead of returning a scalar value, it returns a DataRowView object. Which I consider is due to setting a `DataTable` as the `DataSource`.

Comment: It is correct if you set `comboFindState.ValueMember = "State Code";`

Comment: Also, would you mind explaining why `ValueMember` should be set _before_ `DataSource`? Seems illogical specifying some relative values when the base data is not even available.

Comment: I **have** set `comboFindState.ValueMember = "State Code";`. From the absolute start. Hence the problem.